# Conditional Joint PDF given a value

Tags: probability

Given $f(x,y) = \frac{6-x-y}{8}$ and  $0<x <2$ and $2<y<4$

What is $P(2<Y<3|X = 1) $

How do i approach this problem?

I got the marginal PDF for x $\frac{21}{16} - \frac{3}{8}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In analogy with regular probabilities, where
$$\mathbb{P}(A|B)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(AB)}{\mathbb{P}(B)},$$ 
we define conditional densities as:
$$f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)},$$
whenever the marginal satisfies $f_Y(y)\neq 0$. In your particular problem you already got said marginal, so it is straightforward to compute the conditional density. Once you got the conditional density you ought to remember that we usually have that the probability of a random variable being found in certain region is the integral of its density there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What do i compute for Y?

Comment: Please elaborate, what is this Y?

Comment: (X,Y) in this answer is (Y,X) in the question.

Comment: Do I compute the integral from 3 to 2 and put X as 1? (For the numerator)

Comment: In your case you would have to calculate $f_{Y|X}$ instead of $f_{X|Y}$, in which, yes, you ought to make $x=1$, then integrate.